# OSMdroid: Markers above each other - how to click

Tags: android, android-mapview, marker, osmdroid

I have a big problem with OSMdroid:
I have a map with a bunch of markers, some of them are near each other so that the marker drawables are above each other.
Now, when the user clicks such a marker "stack" the code from the `onClickListener` for each marker is executed.
How can I prevent this execution and instead show a list of the markers "clicked"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Touch` event

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            //Add this item to array        
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            //Show list     
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because it removes the ClickListener from the MapView. I solved it by Overwriting the OverlayItems-Class onTapUpListener to return an array if markers.

Comment: No, this will not remove the clickListener, you could add in the ACTION_DOWN mapview.onClick()